# MySQL return rows ONLY if ALL the rows in another table have a specified value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have two tables

Table1 :

```
efd_details( id )
```

Table2 :

```
efd_detail_status( detail_id  , status )
```

Now the data as following :

```
select * from efd_details;
```

Output :

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
select * from efd_detail_status ;
```

Output :

```
DETAIL_ID | STATUS
1         |   's'
2         |   's'
3         |   's'
4         |   null
5         |   'f'
```

What I need to do is get all the details `(efd_details)` ONLY if ALL the statuses in `efd_detail_status = 's'`. In the example above, I would retrieve ZERO records since two of the status are `!= 's'`. If ALL the `status = 's'` then return ALL rows from `cms_efd`.

I have tried variations of EXISTS and the following:

```
select e.*
  from cms.cms_efd e
where exists(select 1 
               from cms.cms_efd_status s 
              where s.detail_record_id = e.detail_record_id 
                and IFNULL(s.contrib_calc_status,'f') != 's'
             having count(e.detail_record_id)=count(s.detail_record_id))
    and e.earnings_file_id = 400676;
```

[image: cms_efd]
[image: cms_efd_status]
Appreciate the help.
-Branden

Comment: If no other statuses then `SUM(CASE WHEN status = 's' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0`. For to ensure that there is no details without status use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... WHERE status != ... )`

Comment: @RickJames, sorry, that doesn't work. In the images in my comments, 400676 has all statuses that = 's', however, your query returns zero results: ``` select e.*
  from cms.cms_efd e    
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from cms.cms_efd_status s  WHERE IFNULL(s.contrib_calc_status,'f') != 's' )
and e.earnings_file_id = 400676;```

Comment: @RickJames, sorry mate, I left out a filter. This looks promising. select e.*
  from cms.cms_efd e    
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from cms.cms_efd_status s  WHERE s.earnings_file_id=e.earnings_file_id and IFNULL(s.contrib_calc_status,'f') != 's' )
and e.earnings_file_id = 400290;

Answer (score 0):

Turn it around and do something like

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM cms.cms_efd_status
                   WHERE ... != ... )
  AND e.earnings_file_id = 400676
```